# Frequency of non-increasing and non-decreasing subsequences in Matlab

Tags: sequences-and-series, matlab

Having a sequence of numbers of length L, I need to count how many non-decreasing and non-increasing sub-sequences of exact length are there. For example, if I have a sequence of length 15 $$2, 4, 11,13,3,5,5,6,3,3,2,4,2,14,15$$ I see that non-increasing sub-sequences are $$13,3$$
$$6,3,3,2$$
$$4,2$$
and non-decreasing sub-sequences are $$2,4,11,13$$
$$3,5,5,6$$
$$3,3$$
$$2,4$$
$$2,14,15$$
So here I have

- **2 non-increasing sub-sequences of length 2**
- **1 non-increasing sub-sequence of length 4**
- **2 non-decreasing sub-sequences of length 2**
- **1 non-decreasing sub-sequences of length 3**
- **2 non-decreasing subs-equence of length 4**

Since the maximum length of a non-decreasing (or non-increasing) sub-sequence can be 15 in this case, I thought about representing frequencies through vectors **x** for non-increasing and **y** for non-decreasing sub-sequences:
$$x=(0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$$
$$y=(0,2,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$$

Expanding this to general case of sequence of length **L**, I wanted to go through the sequence and, using loops, count frequencies of subsequences of the exact lengths. How would I do that? I would create zero-vectors of length L and I would add 1 to the *l*-th element of zero matrix every time I meet a sub-sequence of length *l*.

Since my sequence will be of length of few thousands, I wouldn't ask Matlab to write them, but I would ask it to write me particular frequency.

Is this a good approach?
Is there some function in Matlab that is doing this?

I will appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: The question may be more appropriate at http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: @LuisMendo Thank you! I will ask there.